# Shared library usage in different Linux namespaces

Tags: linux, namespaces

The Linux namespace can isolate pid, mount poing, network and so on. I use Linux namespace to implement OS-level virtual machine (just like vserver and LXC), but I often run out of memory. I have a question that if I have two processes in different namespaces and they use a same shared library, will the library be loaded once or twice into the physical memory? Besides, what is the underlayer mechanism of library sharing between processes? Is it like the IPC?

Answer (score 4):

If they're all accessing the same file, they should share memory. The mechanism is pretty simple; each process opens the shared object and `mmap(2)`s it. `mmap()` just makes the VFS page cache for the file available in the process's address space, so when multiple processes `mmap()` the same file they get the same pages.

When you have a filesystem mounted multiple times (this is what bind mounts and mounts from multiple namespaces do), there's only one filesystem instance—the multiple mounts are handled at the VFS layer—so it should have only one copy of each file in the cache.

Shared libraries are pretty unlikely to be causing your memory exhaustion; since they're read-only caches of files on disk the kernel will evict them when memory gets tight, causing a disk read whenever a program touches those pages (e.g. invokes a function or accesses memory from the library).